# Which is a better way to search- find with regex or find with grep?

Tags: grep, find

Of these two ways of searching a file recursively in all the subdirectories, which is faster / better ?

```
find . -regex ".*/.*abc.*"
```

or

```
find . | grep ".*abc.*"
```

Comment: `find . -type f -iname "*abc*"` would work...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UNIX file name can generally consist of octets (8-bit bytes), except for 0x00 (NULL) and 0x2F (/). Every other octet is valid. This includes such nice things as 0x0A (newline).

Your `find` example will handle file names with weird characters such as newline correctly.

Your `find | grep` example will give odd and incorrect results when faced with such a thing (it'll see *one* file called "line 1\nline 2" as *two* files).

You can use `find -print0 | grep -z` (if you're using GNU versions, e.g., on Linux); that'll preserve correctness. It'll use a little more memory. Note that you can tell find to use extended regular expressions (for example) using the `-regextype` option.

If you want to do some really complicated matching, you may like the `find2perl` script, which will convert a `find` command line in to a short perl program you can then edit to add in the complexity.

Answer (score 6):

`find . -regex ".*/.*abc.*"` is faster because `find . | grep ".*abc.*"` has to have `find` generate all the data and pass it down to `grep`. The difference is likely to be small though. `find . -regex ".*/.*abc.*"` is also more reliable, because it works even in the rare case where you have file names with spaces.

Note that both commands look for files whose full path contains `abc`. This includes not only files whose name contains `abc` but also files contained in a directory whose name contains `abc`, recursively. To find only files whose name contains `abc`, use

```
find -name '*abc*'
```

In ksh, bash or zsh, you can run `echo **/*abc*` instead: `**/` looks inside all subdirectories recursively. In ksh, you'll need to run `set -o globstar` first (put this in your `~/.kshrc`). In bash, you'll need to run `shopt -s globstar` first (put this in your `~/.bashrc`).

Comment: Why "find has to have `find` generate *all* the data"? As far as I know the data is automatically flushed regularly and passed to the pipe. That's how pipe usually works. Another example: try `yes | cat`. If cat waited for all the data from `yes` which is an infinite stream then it would never finally start writing data to the output.

Comment: @sasha.sochka `find` generates all the data and passes it through the pipe. It does this in parallel with `grep`.

Comment: Oh, yeah, sorry the first time I missed the point .

Answer (score 4):

If you use pattern matching with `find`, you can add other predicates or behaviours:

```
# look only for matching directories
find . -regex ".*/.*abc.*" -type d

# run a command on each match
find . -regex ".*/.*abc.*" -exec echo 'I found a file named {}' ';'
```

`find` might be faster for just searching, too, because you don't need to spawn a `grep` process or perform any piping; but I doubt you would be able to notice.