# Recursive Grep with filename pattern specified

Tags: grep, find

Is it possible to both search recursively and with a given file pattern?

I am trying to do the equivalent of

```
find ./ -name "*.[c|h]" -exec grep -Hn PATTERN {} \;
```

Obviously you can use grep's  -r flag, but when I specify a filename pattern such as:

```
grep -Hn -r PATTERN *.c
```

It only looks for *.c files in the current directory, not recursively.

I found this, but it does not talk about specifying filenames: [Recursive grep vs find / -type f -exec grep {} \; Which is more efficient/faster?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131535/recursive-grep-vs-find-type-f-exec-grep-which-is-more-efficient-faster)

Answer (score 4):

At least with recent versions of GNU `grep`, you can use glob patterns in a `--include` argument

```
grep -Hrn --include="*.[ch]" PATTERN .
```

[In GNU grep > 2.11 you may omit the explicit starting directory `.` when using `-r`]

Comment: _OSX_ `grep` also has that switch though patterns are matched to the full path as opposed to base name in _GNU_

Comment: I am using FreeBSD, this command just waits for STDIN, even though there is an --include flag.

Comment: @FarhanYusufzai that *may* be due to differences in how `grep` selects directories for the `-r` case: even in GNU grep, older versions require an explicit starting directory argument e.g. `grep -Hrn --include="*.[ch]" PATTERN .`

Answer (score 2):

The `*.c` is expanded by the shell before `grep` is even run. With a suitably fancy shell (e.g. `zsh`, or `bash` with `globstar` set), one can pre-expand recursively via something like

```
grep bla **/*.[ch]
```

But that is a shell solution. Other solutions would be to look at the file detection support in such tools as [the silver searcher](http://geoff.greer.fm/ag/), [codesearch](https://github.com/google/codesearch), [ripgrep](http://blog.burntsushi.net/ripgrep/).