# find locations for a given sentence under a directory

Tags: linux, filesystems, find, regular-expression, filenames

Running a program gives some error messages such as these `“ERROR File 'DATA/vgg16.npy' not found`. I know this exact sentence should appear in one or more files under a given directory, which may have multiple subdirectories. Which `linux` command can help me identify the files as well as locations (line number) where that sentence is located.

Comment: As for the part about recursively searching, the answers (and the question itself) [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131535/recursive-grep-vs-find-type-f-exec-grep-which-is-more-efficient-faster) show a number of choices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this command

`grep -r -H 'yourcharacter'`

yourcharacter indicates the particular character for which you are looking for in a file.

the above command will give you the file path of a particular character.